# Novel where child's "true name" is the same as his use name

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this sometime during the mid-90s.  I thought this was Wizard of Earthsea, but I've just reread the beginning and it's apparently not (Ged was originally Duny).

The concept is very similiar to Earthsea, a child goes to get a True Name from a wizard / wise-man.  In this case the wise-man tells the child that their True Name is identical to their child-name/use-name and the boy starts shouting at him and complaining.  The wise-man tells him something about being sorry, but the magic is what decided things.

Comment: any of these? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_name#Folklore_and_Literature
https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IKnowYourTrueName

Comment: The only thing that looks familiar is Earthsea. It might be another book in the Earthsea saga?

Comment: yeah I was curious if it might have been the Earthsea short story described

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is Earthsea, but it's the short story Dragonfly. It's not a boy, and it's not his use name. It's a woman and it's the name of her family's land.

> In a whisper the witch said, “Woman, be named. You are Irian.”
> For a moment longer they held still; then the night wind blew across their
> naked shoulders, and shivering, they waded out, dried themselves as well as
> they could, struggled barefoot and wretched through the sharp-edged reeds
> and tangling roots, and found their way back to the lane. And there Dragonfly
> spoke in a ragged, raging whisper: ‘How could you name me that!”
> The witch said nothing.

....

> “It isn’t right. It isn’t my true name! I thought my name would make me be
> me. But this makes it worse. You got it wrong. You’re only a witch. You did it
> wrong. It’s his name. He can have it. He’s so proud of it, his stupid domain,
> his stupid grandfather. I don’t want it. I won’t have it. It isn’t me. I still don’t
> know who I am. I’m not Irian!” She fell silent abruptly, having spoken the
> name.

....

> “I spoke your true name. It’s not what I thought it would be. And I don’t feel
> easy about it. As if I’d left something unfinished. But it is your name. If it
> betrays you, then that’s the truth of it.” Rose hesitated and then spoke less
> angrily, more coldly: ‘If you want the power to betray me, Irian, I’ll give you
> that. My name is Etaudis.”

Comment: That's it!  Thank you so much for that; it's been bothering me for years. :)

Comment: Looking it up, I'd read it in an anthology book called Legends which also introduced me to the Sword of Truth, Wheel of Time, and Song of Ice and Fire prequel series.